Cannot produce bookmarks for title page after generating pdf file in overleaf
http://tcci.ccf.org.cn/conference/2024/dldoc/llncs2e.zip
I tried to use this template to write a conference paper, but the pdf result, generated by tex file, cannot shows the title bookmarks on the left side bar (However, there is a demo pdf in zip files that shows a title-section outline).
I have tried to add \usepackage{hyperref} before \begin{document} but still cannot show the titles and headings bookmarks.
I see another solution is using bookmark package and add them one by one, but the problem is why it cannot work by using hyperref package?
In detail, it can be worked as following,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    Hello
    \section{Section 1}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \section{Section 2}
\end{document}

but not worked in my template by,
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    Hello
    \section{Section 1}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \section{Section 2}
\end{document}

but why, how to correct it?

Welcome! Please provide a minimal example i.e. code for a small document which reproduces the problem. hyperref should be loaded late, often as the last package unless you know something specifically needs to come later. You must compile at least twice for the bookmarks to show up (unless you use bookmark).

@cfr thanks for your reply, I have add more details in my question

Is this for Lecture Notes in Computer Science? I got to the page a different way as my browser doesn't like your link, but I don't know if it is the same or no. llncs is for a journal published by Springer and available from their site.

@cfr you may download the template from this site I provided, it is llncs2e.zip and it truly a template of conference on NLP
